# Adding Namecheap domain to AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, dns, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, namecheap

i've followed a lot of tutorial but nothing works for me. Right now in DNS configuration i have this:

**TYPE**: URL Redirect record
**HOST**: @
**VALUE**: ebname.eba-random.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com

**TYPE**: CNAME
**HOST**: www
**VALUE**: https://example.com

SSL is already configured. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this the following configuration should work.

Assuming you want the apex/root domain (i.e. `example.com`) to resolve to this application you should use the [Alias](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/10128/2237/how-to-create-an-alias-record) record type specifying the value of your Elastic Beanstalk endpoint `ebname.eba-random.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com`.

With this in place the root record will start to resolve (the current type `URL Redirect record` redirects the root record).

You currently have a `CNAME` for your subdomain (i.e. `www.example.com`). Ensure the value does not include any protocols or paths (you currently have `https` in front). It should go to simply the domain that is a `CNAME` of i.e. `example.com`.

Comment: Following your instuctions it works for http://www. only. Consulting in https://www.whatsmydns.net i'm getting all x in CNAME, but all ok in A

Comment: Did you update your CNAME to remove the protocol (https)?

Comment: i think there is no way to do that anymore, unless the domain has been purchased from amazon.

Comment: It’s definitely possible as it is valid DNS configuration. Can you confirm your CNAME is going to just the domain? When you perform DIG does it resolve?

Comment: by applying this configuration: https://medium.com/@ryan_waits/using-aws-elastic-beanstalk-and-namecheap-to-deploy-and-host-your-node-js-app-dc4129d0eb2c now it's only in: http://example.com

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue using a domain from porkbun.
The solution ended up being to first:

1. in your EC2 page, click "load balancers" from the left menu
2. add make sure both http and https are under Listener ID.
3. go into route53, create an A record and choose under Value/Route traffic to
   a) alias to application and classic load balancer
   b) choose the region
   c) choose the load balancer/environment

In my porkbun, I had to put the authorized nameservers from route53, not sure if namecheap has something similar.